# Start new thred from asynk task in android

Tags: android

In my application i made service call to fetch images from server.For this i have used asynk task class.For image loading I'm using lazy loading.Now the problem is,when i make call for loading images from background method of asynk task then the screen becomes blank for some time and then i see the progress bar.When i made trace for it i found out that i should start image loading in a new thread.So i want to know how to start a new thread within asynk task background method.Please help me..I'm new to this.Below is my code..

```
public class GetRestaurentDetails extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
{

    Context context;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    public GetRestaurentDetails(Context c) {
        this.context=c;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        this.progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(context,"","Please wait...");

    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

        onGetRestaurentDetails();
        listAdapter = new RestaurantLidtAdapter(arrImages);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

And Adapter class

```
private class RestaurantLidtAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Holder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public RestaurantLidtAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrImages){

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(RestaurantListActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return arrPromotions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(convertView == null){

            holder = new Holder();
            convertView = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurantlistrowlayout, parent, false);
            holder.imgArrowImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgArrowInHotelList);
            holder.imgHotelImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowHotelImage);
            holder.txtRestaurentPromotion = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewPromotions);
            holder.txtRestaurentName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewRestaurentName);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();


        }

        //holder.imgHotelImage.setImageBitmap(loadBitmap(arrImages.get(position)));


        imageLoader.DisplayImage(arrImages.get(position), holder.imgHotelImage);
        holder.txtRestaurentPromotion.setText(arrPromotions.get(position));
        holder.txtRestaurentName.setText(arrRestaurentName.get(position));
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        return convertView;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using ImageLoader class from the Lazy loading listview code, i think you don't need to implement AsyncTask because you are just creating adapter and set it to the ListView inside the doInBackground() method.

And there is an issue obvious because you are trying to create adapter in background process which is not preferable and you should setAdapter only once inside the onPostExecute() other than doInBackground().

And now, the solution which i suggest to you is remove those 2 lines from the AsyncTask and pass Images URL to adapter class directly.

Comment: @android be more specific about why it doesn't solve your problem? I am still having doubt about your AsyncTask declaration for only creating adapter and setting it to ListView.